# Angular: how to share a (controller)$scope between 2 separate divs?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <h1>My App</h1>
  <div id="search" ng-controller="TagsController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="tags_to_search" />
    <button ng-click="search(tags_to_search)" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="results" ng-controller="TagsController">
    going to search {{tags_to_search}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="tag in searched_tags">
        {{tag.name}} - {{tag.counter}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="DataController">

  </div>
</div>
```

The TagsController $scope includes a searched_tags which is populated when the button is clicked, so the #search div is supposed to update the #results div (when the button is clicked, and when the textbox is populated).

In fact, nothing happens and they both look unrelated although I set the same controller for both #search and #results. I can have a wrapper div that will take the TagsController instead of the #search and #results div, but my UI is built in a way that such a wrapper will cause the DataController to be nested in the Tags controller although it's totally wrong logically and they have nothing to do together.

Any suggestions how I can go through this?

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work?

```
<div ng-controller="TagsController">
    <h1>My App</h1>
    <div id="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Data controller has nothing to do with Tags controller and you don't want it nested, can you go with this?

```
<div ng-controller="TagsController">
  <h1>My App</h1>
  <div id="search" >
    <input type="text" ng-model="tags_to_search" />
    <button ng-click="search(tags_to_search)" />
  </div>
  <div id="results" >
    going to search {{tags_to_search}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="tag in searched_tags">
        {{tag.name}} - {{tag.counter}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="DataController">

</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be helpful because I simplified my real code in order to keep it thin and understandable. You'll have to assume that the layout and the controller code should be unchanged :/

Comment: ok - in your controller code, does searched_tags have correct values?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? it's an array of JSON objects.